# How to show same column in dbgrid with different criteria

Tags: delphi, ms-access, select, dbgrid

i need your help to finish my delphi homework.

I use ms access database and show all data in 1 dbgrid using sql. I want to show same column but with criteria (50 record per column)
i want select query to produce output like:

```
No   | Name | No    | Name |
1    | A    | 51    | AA   | 
2    | B    | 52    | BB   | 
3~50 |      | 53~100|      |
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: It's okay to ask homework related questions as long as you're not just asking us to answer them, which doesn't seem to be the case here. Just make sure you include examples of the things you've tried. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Dan I would say "as long as you're not just asking us to do your work for you." because "answering" is directly related to Stack Overflow answers. The fact that it's homework is irrelevant. "homework" could mean either for school, work, or personal development which should be a standard part of any developer.

Comment: thanks for your feedback Dodge, I actually have a document I save these default messages for newbies so they can learn how to improve. I'll update the language.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge, my apologies... I think it might be time to stop staring at my computer screen for the night lol.

Comment: @JerryDodge sorry, i think both sql server and ms access are same. I still confused to learn SQL that show records like that. I don't know the correct keyword to search the answer in google.

Comment: @Robby `SQL Server` is a very mature and extensive database engine provided by Microsoft, whereas `MS Access` is a very lightweight and user-friendly database engine also provided by Microsoft. They both support `SQL` script, however the way the script works can be quite different. For comparison, `SQL Server` is used by huge organizations, even banks. `MS Access` however would never be used by something like a bank. Access is like an excel spreadsheet on steroids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can foresee issues if you choose to return a dataset with duplicate column names. To fix this, you must change your query to enforce strictly unique column names, using `as`. For example...

```
select A.No as No, A.Name as Name, B.No as No2, B.Name as Name2 from TableA A
  join TableB B on B.Something = A.Something
```

Just as a note, if you're using a `TDBGrid`, you can customize the column titles. Right-click on the grid control in design-time and select `Columns Editor...` and a Collection window will appear. When adding a column, link it to a `FieldName` and then assign a value to `Title.Caption`. This will also require that you set up all columns. When you don't define any columns here, it automatically returns all columns in the query.

On the other hand, a SQL query may contain duplicate field names in the output, depending on how you structure the query. I know this is possible in `SQL Server`, but I'm not sure about `MS Access`. In any case, I recommend always returning a dataset with unique column names and then customizing the DB Grid's column titles. After all, it is also possible to connect to an excel spreadsheet, which can very likely have identical column names. The problem arrives when you try to read from one of those columns for another use.

Comment: I have add all columns in the columns editor but how to show the records? The dbgrid doesn't show anything.

Comment: If that's the problem you're having then you have an entirely different question. Do you have any records without adding custom columns?

Comment: Yes my dbgrid show all records before i add custom columns.. But just 1 column 'No' and 1 column 'Name'

Comment: On second though, if your query really does return two different field names, then you need to change your query.

Comment: On your example there is TableA and TableB , but i just select from 1 table. @jerry Dodge thanks for your attention and helps, I will learn more about sql first and fix it later.

Comment: @Robby Again, it depends on the actual database engine you're using. If you're selecting from just one table, SQL Server most definitely does not allow duplicate field names. But Access on the other hand might, however I'm not familiar with Access.

Comment: Now that you've removed your `sql-server` tag, indicating you're actually using `ms-access`, I'm questioning whether my answer is even useful or not.